# Replace Old Back Tire Where to Replace New

Tags: tires

I need to replace old tire at the back only. Where should I put the new tire?

Should I place it on the front or back?

Comment: At least fit an axle set. But depending on the car you may need all 4. To avoid transmission / drivetrain damage.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're replacing a tire on the back, you should put the new tire where the old tire was, obviously.

Comment: If it's a single tyre, pair it with the best of the 3 remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a two wheel drive car, you should replace the tires as a pair on the same axle.

If you loose grip on the rear of the car, it is more difficult to regain control of the car than if you loose grip on the front.  Therefore it is best to put new tyres on the rear of the car to lessen the chance of loosing grip at the rear.

See this [page](https://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/how-to/a3121/6-common-tire-myths-debunked-10031440/) which debunks the myth - “When replacing only two tires, the new ones go on the front”

Comment: Can get control back by judicious use of throttle... and with front wheel drive in snow the back end can be caught easily - case of having to learn when living with lots of snow.